# Image Bundle location

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-designer

Where do I need to put my Image Bundle (derived from a ClientBundle) for GWT Designer to find them?

I've tried doing `add` in the Image Bundle Palette and GWT Designer can't find my bundle.

How do I achieve this?

GWT SDK 2.5.0RC1, Eclipse Helios (3.6)

Comment: I'm not using the designer, but are you sure "Image Bundle Palette" doesn't refer to `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ImageBundle` rather than `ClientBundle`s with `ImageResource`s?

Comment: `Image Bundle Palette` is a GWT Designer feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ImageBundle Palette" is apparently about `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ImageBundle`s, not about `com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle`.

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/palettes/gwt_palette and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/image_bundles

Comment: Ah, that would explain it! Thanks.